# Print to file with Python cron job. File is created, but is empty

Tags: python, cron

I am trying to print to a file when executing a .py started with cron.

I have a file test.py. All it says is:

print "hello"

If I execute test.py from the command line then cron_log.txt is generated and says "hello".

```
python2.7 /home/path/test.py >> /home/path/cron_log.txt
```

However, if I run the exact same command as a cron job then cron_log.txt is created, but it is empty:

```
57 21 * * * python2.7 /home/path/test.py >> /home/path/cron_log.txt
```

The host is webfaction. Linux.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I added  2>&1 to the end of the command and it worked.

```
57 21 * * * python2.7 /home/path/test.py >> /home/path/cron_log.txt 2>&1
```

Answer (score 0):

I have the exact same situation using Python3 on Ubuntu, unfortunately simply adding 2>&1 did not solve immediately the issue of a blank Ctools-output.log:

```
@reboot /usr/bin/python3 /opt/scripts/Ctools.py >> ~/Ctools-output.log 2>&1
```

It turns out that python standard output is buffered by default in blocks, which differs from terminal output that is buffered by line.  It could take a considerable about of time before the buffered block is full and then Python writes it off to the output file.  The above will work, eventually, but considerable delay.

**The solution to my issue was force flushing so there was no buffering of output within Python and output was immediately written:**

```
python3 -u myscript.py
```

Now I can run my Python script upon reboot using cron and the output is immediately outputted to the log file:

```
@reboot /usr/bin/python3 -u /opt/scripts/Ctools.py >> ~/Ctools-output.log 2>&1
```